The Heat Generation and heat flux both in General Heat Conduction Equation
How would I incorporate both heat generated within and element and heat flux from external to the element in GHCE.
For example,

Let there be a thick wall of thickness 'L', with internal heat generation of Q_g. There is also heat flux flowing from the left plant towards right of value Q_f. How will I calculate the temperature distribution for this?

I know from GHCE in One-Dimension,

Thus, for simple heat generation I can just add values to Q_g and get the distribution but what do I do when there is also a heat flux? I can't simply put end temperatures because I just do not know (as they will depend on both heat generation  (Q_g) and heat flux (Q_f) , I think)

I think if you know heat flux at a coordinate, you know also $\frac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}x}$ at that coordinate.

The heat flux at one end is a boundary condition.  It makes the problem a transient one.  A constant heat flux makes the temperatures go to infinity without any cooling (heat output) considered as an additional boundary condition.
